# how to find URLs accessed by a process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

Is there a way to monitor and get a listing of URLs accessed over HTTP by a process running in my local machine? Failing that, what would be closer to the above information? My use case is that I have an effectively opaque utility that I suspect is downloading some information over the web and I would like to see what exactly it is fetching over the network.

Comment: Web server logs ... ?

Comment: @KM I don't own the web server(s) and don't know which servers get contacted to begin with. I am on the client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/) to do this. From the website:

> tcpflow is a program that captures data transmitted as part of TCP connections (flows), and stores the data in a way that is convenient for protocol analysis or debugging. A program like 'tcpdump' shows a summary of packets seen on the wire, but usually doesn't store the data that's actually being transmitted. In contrast, tcpflow reconstructs the actual data streams and stores each flow in a separate file for later analysis.

It will dump logs into the current working directory in the format [ip].[port]-[ip].[port].

```
# mkdir http_logs
# cd http_logs
# tcpflow dst port 80
```

This example logs all TCP packets going to port 80, and saves them in the current directory for easy debugging. You can also filter further using [pcap filters](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html).

You might also find the `-a` switch useful, which enables post processing. For example, it puts the HTTP headers and bodies in separate files.

Answer (score 5):

If it's an open-source program, the obvious answer it to look at the source code... **;-)**  *However*, if you have a closed-source program whose network usage you want to monitor, the best to do is connect both the machine that contains the suspicious application  and a machine containing a network sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) into a [hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub).

**Why an external machine?**  There have been applications in the past that would disable certain "hidden features" if they detected a sniffer running on the same machine.

P.S. As hubs are increasingly becoming industrial archaeology, you can also use a spanned port on a (professional) switch.

[image: spanned port]

On consumer-grade switches, spanning is normally not available unfortunately.